# Failed to generate random CSRF token! (phpmyadmin 4.6.4)

Tags: php, phpmyadmin

I installed newest versions of MySQL, IIS (on windows 10) and PHPMyAdmin.

But PHPMyAdmin 4.6.4 returns an error:

> Failed to generate random CSRF token!

If I use PHPMyAdmin 4.0.4.1 I can connect to my local mysql server.

How can I fix this problem in PHPMyAdmin 4.6.4 (on windows IIS)?

Comment: I had this error too, out from nowhere (I didn't install new software, just updated one game...). So I changed Apache port number, and it helped.

Answer (score 7):

modify php.ini :

```
session.save_path = "c:\session"
```

grant modify `c:\session` permission to USERS

run command: `iisreset`

Comment: I have the same phpamdin error question on appserv in windows version. How can I grant the permission to USERS? Can you help me? I reinstall the appserv last time happend, now it happens again. I don't know how come the error...

Comment: how do I grant modify c:\session permission to USERS? do I run the iisreset command from command prompt? please elaborate, I'm very new to these technical setup stuff..

Answer (score 3):

royhutw is kind of right.

The default session.save_path is C:\Windows\Temp. If you're getting this error IIS probably doesn't have permissions to create a session file there.

Only thing you'll have to do is give "IUSR" modify permissions on this folder and reload your phpMyAdmin page.

Answer (score 2):

I will write here, maybe it will be useful to someone.
I have a similar problem but with mysql 8 on debian 9 and sometimes I get an error token.
This kind of stupid solution works for me:
I change the line in php.ini:

```
session.save_path = "/ var / lib / php / sessions"
```

For anything, later I run:

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

And once again I change the exchange line above to the correct one and reset again and I can log in to phpmyadmin ...

Answer (score 0):

In the web browser, manually delete the entry "phpMyAdmin", it will be solved easily. For mine it worked!