# php v5.6.30 breaks phpmyadmin (Failed to generate random CSRF token)

Tags: php, phpmyadmin

I have been running phpMyAdmin (currently v4.6.6) on a Windows 2012 R2 server for some time now.  Last week I upgraded PHP to version 5.6.30 and it causes phpMyAdmin to generate an error on the phpMyAdmin login screen:

> Failed to generate random CSRF token

I can switch back to the previous PHP version (v5.6.21) and it works fine.  So for now I'm running the older version.  Any idea what changes I need to make to PHP to get v5.6.30 to work?  My PHP.ini file is identical between the two, except that I modified the PHP error log filename.

The back-end database is MySQL v5.7.17.

Comment: Does this help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40611591/failed-to-generate-random-csrf-token-phpmyadmin-4-6-4

Comment: I had already looked at that article, and I added the IIS_IUSRS group with modify permissions to that directory. But the IIS_IUSRS group does not include the IUSR user. I went back and explicitly added the IUSR user to have modify permissions to that directory and boom, it worked. Thanks AbraCadaver.