# phpMyAdmin Failed to generate random CSRF token! phpMyAdmin 4.6.6 on windows

Tags: php, phpmyadmin, windows-7-x64, sql-grant, appserver

```
phpMyAdmin - Error
Failed to generate random CSRF token!
```

It happened suddenly on my appserv on windows

I search the answer from 
[Failed to generate random CSRF token! (phpmyadmin 4.6.4)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40611591/failed-to-generate-random-csrf-token-phpmyadmin-4-6-4)

modify php.ini :

```
session.save_path = "c:\session"
grant modify c:\session permission to USERS

run command: iisreset
```

But I donot know how to grant permission to USERS

on my windows

My php.ini

```
session.save_path = "C:/Users/android/AppData/Local/Temp"
```

The folder is still in and many files in it~

Any suggestion? Thanks a lot~

Comment: Any one can help me? I reinstal the appserv twice. It works well for a while then happpend suddenly~

Answer (score 2):

I find the solution~
clear the chrome cache.
Solved~